# Imagine with Yii, issue with palette / color

Tags: php, yii, colors, palette, php-imagine

I installed Yii and Imagine with composer and tried to use imagine.
the issue is when i try to use this code from the imagine website introduction i got an error 500 :

`Argument 2 passed to Imagine\Gd\Imagine::create() must be an instance of Imagine\Image\Color, instance of Imagine\Image\Palette\Color\RGB given`

code:

```
    use Imagine\Image\Box;
    $imagine = new Imagine\Gd\Imagine();
    $palette = new Imagine\Image\Palette\RGB();
    $size  = new Box(400, 300);
    $color = $palette->color('#000', 100);
    $image = $imagine->create($size, $color);
    $image->save('images/test.png');
```

when i edit this line :

```
    $image = $imagine->create($size, $color);
```

with

```
   $image = $imagine->create($size);
```

the picture is created white so i guess Imagine is working

Did i miss something ? Do i have to change something in the config or something else ?

Any idea will be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Is your Imagine plugin newest version? Your code works fine with me (with $color). The plugin which I got from https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine

Comment: it's the master version as i get it with composer